# I want to display predefined HTML in a variable

Tags: codeigniter, smarty

I am using Codeigniter and everything works just fine. I can assign PHP variable to smarty an display them.

But now I am calling a webservice and this webservice returns a complete HTML (and javascript) page.
I want to display this in a smarty template.

So I have done the following:
I have assigned the output of the webservice to a PHP variable and assigned this to a smarty variable (`HTMLstring`), like I always do. That part works.
In my smarty template I don't need anything but to display the contents of the variable. So my template contains just one line:

```
{HTMLstring}
```

But this displays the literal HTML including tags and all. I want to display the output.

(If I copy-paste the output in a separate html file, and open that, it just looks fine)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it (first had to install the unescape plugin), but it doesn't work. If I make it simplier: HTMLstring='<h1>Test this</h1>'; That is just what I see, so including the h1-tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that your HTMLString has PHP code that you want to be parsed before the HTML content is included?

Comment: No PHP code. Just plain HTML.

Comment: Seems to have been solved. It appears it makes a difference if I call the template from code or just type the complete url in my browser for testing purposes. The latter didn't work, the former does.   One newby question left: how do I close this question?

Comment: Post your solution as an answer below, not as a comment. Then you can accept and close it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I 'figured out' the answer.
It appears it makes a difference if I call the template from code or just type the complete url in my browser for testing purposes. The latter didn't work, the former does. I still don't know why.  Sorry...
Question closed.

Comment: That is not very useful, "I figured out the answer", please edit this to include what the answer actually is.